# Blocking socket send() call time cost

Tags: sockets, send

Good Day!
It seems the calling of send() function for blocking socket has only to copy an app buffer into the kernel driver network buffer. I thought it must be very fast if driver buffer is empty. It must cost  only one system call (context change).

On my system a simple system call costs about 2500 tsc counter ticks ~ 0.5-1.0 mcs.

But my measurements contradict the above conclusions.

Here is the example of code.

```
uint32_t garb;
uint64_t t0 = __rdtscp(&garb); 

iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);

uint64_t t1 = __rdtscp(&garb);

std::cout << "CORE SENT (" << (t1 - t0)/1000  << "k ticks)\n" << std::flush;
```

I have tried such code on Windows 10 system with VS2015 compiler and MSYS2 (MingW) gcc compiler with small size data to send (about 14 bytes for example). In all cases such code costs (t1-t0) about 100k-350k ticks with average about 250k ticks. Id est it costs about 25-80 mcs with average 60 mcs. It's much more than a simple system call+memory copying. The send calling time never goes under 100k ticks and it doesn't seem as any cache miss.

Is it normal behaviour or not? Can you explain me it? May be send function takes some another overhead. Why may the send calling time be constantly mush more than a simple system call+memory copying. Is it problem on my sistem? Is it the same cost on linux system?